# qsub and python, imports .py modules but returns ImportError for .pyf

Tags: python, module, importerror, qsub

I am trying to submit a job via `qsub myScript.sh -cwd`, where the shell script runs a Python-2.7 script, `myPython.py`.

```
    # myScript.sh
    python2.7 myPython.py
```

Now, `myPython.py` needs to import a Python package that is stored in my local directory so the script starts with

```
    # myPython.py
    import sys
    sys.path.append('/file/path/for/package')
    import package
```

After submitting the job, the log file contains the following output from Python:

```
    ImportError: No module named problem_c
```

This error occurs after several modules have been imported from `*.py` files without returning errors, so I am fairly certain that this is not a problem with the path. The only difference I find is that the `problem_c` file ends in `.pyf` (i.e. `problem_c.pyf`). It is stored in the same directory as the the modules ending in `.py`.

When I run the script locally, as `python2.7 myPython.py`, this error does not occur when the package loads. However, the job is too memory intensive to complete without submitting it to queue. Why are modules written as `.pyf` files being treated differently when I use `qsub`, and how can I import them in this case?

(If it matters, the cluster I'm working on was set up with Sun Grid Engine.)

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: Is the `.pyf` a `pyfort` (Fortran in Python) file?  If so, do you have `pyfort` installed on your local machine but not on the cluster machines?

Comment: should it not be `sys.path.append(0,'/file/path/for/package')`?

Comment: @TobSpr I get an error saying `sys.path.append` takes only 1 argument when I try that.

Comment: @dg99 the `.pyf` does seem to be a `pyfort` file, but as far as I can see `pyfort` is not installed in either location. There are also `.c` and `.h` files in the directory for `package`. Are these not readable as modules by Python?

Answer (score 0):

Or f2py. It's obviously you didn't add the module on your cluster.

Comment: To make this an answer, you should elaborate it. now it is merely a comment.

Comment: I did find `f2py` locally, so does that explain why the `.pyf` module works when I don't run on the cluster? What is the simplest way to "add the module" on the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can import a module with its path:

```
import imp
module_name = imp.load_source('module_name', '/abs/path/to/module/module_name.py')

# usage
module_name.function()
```